# Which version of Spring AMQP and Spring Rabbit is compatible with Spring 5?

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am getting errors out of Spring Rabbit and Spring AMQP after an upgrade to Spring 5.

Both are now set to 1.5.6.RELEASE

Does anyone know which releases are supposed to be compatible with Spring 5?

More generally does anyone know if somewhere there is a masterlist of compatibile versions of Spring projects kept anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [recently announced](https://spring.io/blog/2017/10/05/spring-amqp-2-0-0-release-available) 2.0.0.RELEASE is compatible with Spring Framework 5.0.

The [project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/) is the place to start; the link to the reference manual provides framework [compatibility information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_introduction.html#compatibility) for each version.